# How to get specific value into the view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table players with id, name, etc about player. I also have a table players_achievements that looks like

```
playerid | shortname | score
----------------------------------
    1    | someName  | someScore
    1    | otherName | otherScore
    1    | FOTOCASH  | integerValue
    2    | someName  | someScore
    2    | otherName | otherScore
    2    | FOTOCASH  | integerValue
   ...
```

I know it's stupid, I didn't create this, but I have to get score when shortname is equal to FOTOCASH. It would be easy done using

SELECT score FROM players_achievements WHERE playerid = id AND shortname = 'FOTOCASH'

But I have to do this inside some View, and if returned value doesn't exist, I want to insert 'No'.
So I tried to:

```
CASE players_achievements.playerid
    WHEN players.id THEN 
        CASE players_achievements.shortname
            WHEN 'FOTOCASH' THEN CONCAT(players_achievements.score, ' $')
        END
    ELSE 'No'
END AS 'Fotocash'
```

But this doesn't work well. Now I have 7 rows (becouse every player can have maximally 8 rows in achievements table) with value None and one with wanted value Fotocash

```
playerid | Fotocash | rest of columns
-------------------------------
    1    |   Null   | rest of values
    1    |   Null   | rest of values
    1    |  17500$  | rest of values
    2    |   Null   | rest of values
    2    |   3000$  | rest of values
    2    |   Null   | rest of values
...
```

I want this looks like

```
playerid | Fotocash | rest of columns
-------------------------------------
    1    |  17500$  | rest of values
    2    |   3000$  | rest of values
...
```

I used RIGHT JOIN but tried also INNER and LEFT

```
RIGHT JOIN `db`.`players_achievements` on((`db`.`players_achievements`.`playerid` = `db`.`players`.`id`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the rest of your query I am guessing, but what is wrong with using

```
WHERE Fotocash IS NOT NULL
```

?

(Stick with LEFT JOIN if you can, it often makes things easier...Assuming the LEFT hand table is your major source of data)

Comment: Where should I put this clause?

Comment: After your select and your joins, and before your order by clause if any (ie at the end)

Comment: Unknown column 'Fotocash' in 'where clause'
Checked three times, column name is corect...

Comment: I wasnt sure of your query syntax but glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join` like this:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(CONCAT(pa.score, '$'), 'NO') as FotoCashScore
FROM players p LEFT JOIN
     players_achievements pa
     ON pa.playerid = p.id AND pa.shortname = 'FOTOCASH';
```

Comment: ERROR  Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @rop .  . . I don't understand your comment.

Comment: My IDE says that, and highlights 'Coalesce'

Comment: @rop . . . I don't understand.  `coalesce()` is a perfectly valid function in MySQL and it accepts at least two arguments.  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: I am not an expert, I don't know, why it didn't want to work. Maybe because I have 70 lines of SQL, and, some of them caused some problems.